# How to activate a Redstone lamp with a Command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a tower of redstone lamps. Is it possible to activate one of them without activating another lamp with a command block, and if there is, what code can I use to connect a Command block to a redstone lamp?

Comment: Welcome here, don't hesitate to take [the tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [the help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need.

Comment: To those voting to close this question as "Too Broad", I really don't see how this question is too broad. It can be solved with a relatively simple command. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

**Light a single lamp**

You can use a command like this:

```
/setblock 100 100 100 minecraft:redstone_lamp[lit=true]
```

The redstone lamp will turn back off after it receives a block update, so make sure to test your setup propperly. If this doesn't work for your setup, then try to use a repeating command block.

**Light multiple lamps in a certain volume**

You can use a command like this:

```
/fill 100 100 100 110 110 110 minecraft:redstone_lamp[lit=true] replace minecraft:redstone_lamp
```

It will light all the redstone lamps within the specified area. If lamps that get lit with this command touch eachother, they will provide a block update for each other and they will turn off again. You can use a repeating command block to solve this issue, too.

Comment: If I want to activait multipal light at the same time, what code most I use then if I wanna to it at the same command_block?

Comment: You could use something like `/fill 100 100 100 110 110 110 minecraft:redstone_lamp[lit=true] replace minecraft:redstone_lamp[lit=false]`. I'm not sure how well this would work, but it should work.